# German word for "suspension" / "suspended harmony" (music theory)

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request, music

I'm searching for a German word for *suspension*, referring to music theory. *Suspension* as in *suspended harmony*.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonchord_tone#Suspension):

> A suspension (SUS) (sometimes referred to as a syncope) occurs when the harmony shifts from one chord to another, but one or more notes of the first chord (the "Preparation") are either temporarily held over into or are played again against the second chord (against which they are nonchord tones called the "Suspension") before resolving to a chord tone stepwise (the "Resolution").

I've tried several dictonaries, none of which seem to have a translation that is used to refer to that specific phenomenon. Is there a German word for that? If not, how could you describe it using as less words as possible (in German)?

Comment: BTW, a good way to find such words is the [German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategorie:Harmonielehre). If there was an entry for "suspension_(music)" instead of "nonchord tone" in the English Wikipedia, there probably would be a direct link to the German version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called "der Vorhalt". [(example)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorhalt_%28Musik%29#mediaviewer/File:Vorhalt_musik_2.jpg)